# Unable to install WSUS 3.0 sp2 on Server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, wsus

I have `Windows server 2008 R2 standard edition` and previously `WSUS 3.0 SP2` server was work but unfortunately service not starting up, So that I tried to complete uninstall from registry, database and wsus folders etc, Now getting below error when i trying to install wsus server(even trying to install `wsus3.0 SP1`) :

[image]

Even I'm tring setup with `Internal database` as well as `SQLServer` and `SQLEXpress`. Any one have idea about this error?

Comment: Ravi - I see here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/85d37240-e175-44aa-859b-9ed1e5d689a2/wsus-w2k8-there-is-a-problem-with-this-windows-installer-package-a-program-run-as-part-of-the?forum=winserverwsus that you want to ensure the drive is not compressed... check this setting in case it's as simple as that. Additionally, check the drive you are installing this on or see how much "C" drive space is available in case that's the issue.

Comment: Here's another post mentioning similar issues with the compression of the drive or folder the WSUS installs to. https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26169385/Can't-get-WSUS-installed-on-Svr-2008-R2.html

Answer (score -3):

I know it's been posted a long time ago...
I faced the same problem some days ago. You have to install/enable .net 3.5 at your server features.

Add/remove programs --> Enable windows features